# Deploy ASP.NET Core to Azure VM - dotnet: command not found

Tags: asp.net-core, github-actions

I have a VM set up in Microsoft Azure. I'm deploying an ASP.NET Core app via GitHub Actions to the Azure VM.

Every step in the `deploy.yml` file completes successfully, except the final step which throws an error

> dotnet: command not found

despite `dotnet` being installed and me exporting the path.

There seems to be some issue with the path, given it cannot find dotnet.

Here is the `deploy.yml` file:

```
name: Deploy to Azure VM

on:
  push:
    branches:
      - main

jobs:
  deploy:
    runs-on: ubuntu-latest

    steps:
    - name: Checkout repository
      uses: actions/checkout@v2

    - name: Setup .NET Core
      uses: actions/setup-dotnet@v1
      with:
        dotnet-version: '8.x'

    - name: Cache .NET packages
      uses: actions/cache@v2
      with:
        path: |
          ~/.nuget/packages
          ~/.dotnet
        key: ${{ runner.os }}-dotnet-${{ hashFiles('**/*.csproj') }}
        restore-keys: |
          ${{ runner.os }}-dotnet-

    - name: Install .NET Core on Azure VM
      uses: appleboy/ssh-action@master
      with:
        host: ${{ secrets.AZURE_VM_IP_ADDRESS }}
        username: ${{ secrets.AZURE_VM_USERNAME }}
        key: ${{ secrets.AZURE_VM_SSH_PRIVATE_KEY }}
        script: |
          wget https://dot.net/v1/dotnet-install.sh
          chmod +x dotnet-install.sh
          sudo ./dotnet-install.sh --install-dir /usr/share/dotnet --version latest
          export PATH=$PATH:/usr/share/dotnet

    - name: Build and publish ASP.NET Core app
      run: |
        dotnet restore
        dotnet build -c Release
        dotnet publish -c Release -o ./publish

    - name: Cache published files
      uses: actions/cache@v2
      with:
        path: |
          ./publish
        key: ${{ runner.os }}-dotnet-publish-${{ hashFiles('**/*.csproj') }}
        restore-keys: |
          ${{ runner.os }}-dotnet-publish-

    - name: Create /applocation folder on Azure VM
      uses: appleboy/ssh-action@master
      with:
        host: ${{ secrets.AZURE_VM_IP_ADDRESS }}
        username: ${{ secrets.AZURE_VM_USERNAME }}
        key: ${{ secrets.AZURE_VM_SSH_PRIVATE_KEY }}
        script: |
          sudo mkdir -p /applocation
          sudo chown $USER:$USER /applocation

    - name: Copy files to Azure VM
      uses: appleboy/scp-action@master
      with:
        host: ${{ secrets.AZURE_VM_IP_ADDRESS }}
        username: ${{ secrets.AZURE_VM_USERNAME }}
        key: ${{ secrets.AZURE_VM_SSH_PRIVATE_KEY }}
        source: './publish'
        target: '/applocation'

    - name: SSH into Azure VM and deploy
      uses: appleboy/ssh-action@master
      with:
        host: ${{ secrets.AZURE_VM_IP_ADDRESS }}
        username: ${{ secrets.AZURE_VM_USERNAME }}
        key: ${{ secrets.AZURE_VM_SSH_PRIVATE_KEY }}
        script: |
          cd /applocation
          source ~/.bashrc || source ~/.bash_profile || true
          export PATH=$PATH:/usr/share/dotnet
          echo "Current PATH: $PATH"
          which dotnet || true
          dotnet AzureVirtualMachineDeploymentDemo2.dll

    - name: Clean up
      run: |
        rm -rf ./publish
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I dont think `export PATH=$PATH:/usr/share/dotnet` is sufficient between jobs. You could hard-code the path so `dotnet restore` becomes `/usr/share/dotnet/dotnet restore` etc to side-step the problem, or you can add `uses` and `with` statements to propagate the environment variables between jobs